# How to open and convert .D0# files

Tags: database, format, legacy

I've got a real toughie.  I have some old data files in a .D0# (like .D01, .D02 etc) format.  I have no idea how these were generated or how to extract them to like a CSV or something simple.  If i open them as text, some of the strings are there but i do not really have a feel for the encoding.

Any help would be life saving!

Here is a share link to a sample of such a file:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wx0k997p6td38l2/KFtp4SieZ1

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well using HxD (a hex editor for Windows) I get the following out of the very beginning of the file:

```
V5.00  Copyright (C) by Compulife Software Inc., 1993
```

Googling Compulife Software took me [here](http://www.compulife.com). Their products are [here](http://www.compulife.com/products.php).

A bit more digging around gives:

```
Compulife offers an historical CD which contains past editions of our software. 
The CD also contains instructions about how to install the past editions, 
which are in a zipped format. 

The history covers almost every month from the current month back to:

April 1990
```

The hex dump said 1993, so there may be some hope here. I'd say your best bet is to contact Compulife themselves. Failing that I can say that the file appears to have a fixed length record format, with some data as text and some in other 8 or 16bit encodings.

I'd start charging about now.